# How to store new object in arraylist without deleting existing once

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that creates object and store it into arrayList. I am running the method in "console menu", so if I run the addObject method 3 times and print the arrayList I want to have 3 objects as content of the arrayList. I want the arrayList index to keep increasing as long I the meun runs. list.add(bk) deletes existing object and create new one. How do I correct the below code to make the method insert new object and not deleting existing one.

**code**

```
public static void addObject() {
        String name, note;
        double price;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter note: ");
        note = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter price: ");
        price = input.nextDouble();


        storeItem bk = new storeItem(name, note, price);

        //how do I complete this part?
        ArrayList<storeItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(bk); //detetes existing and add current. I want to keep existing and add new

        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println("Object: "+ index + "\n" + list.get(index));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the declaration (and initialization) of your `List` from with-in the method to outside of the method. And prefer the `List` interface to the concrete `ArrayList` type. For example,

```
private static List<storeItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Finally, by Java naming conventions, the *class* `storeItem` should be named `StoreItem`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please how do I then call the "list" within the addObject method?

Comment: `list.add(bk);` (after removing the current declaration).